# Halt, not power down, a windows server

Tags: windows, ups, power-supply-unit, shutdown, halt

A client recently changed their UPS and now claims that their server is not coming back up after am extended power outage. They have tested their system and it will keep the last state, so if the power is removed while on, it will automatically power up again.

The question is, in Linux you can request a *halt* so that when power returns it will restart, but how do you do the same in Windows Server?

Comment: I think ACPI driver of your motherboard  isn't installed on Windows.

Comment: Windows 2003 and older operating systems are no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to set your BIOS / UEFI settings for power state to "always on" rather than attempting to restore the machine to its last state. This way, when power is cycled to the PSU (when replacing a PDU, for example) the machine turns on no matter how it was turned off.